# Laravel Query Error - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: laravel

Am trying to get the total sum for amount from in table for a particular month, but I got this error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>
> 'currentmonthbilling' => object(Builder),

The table name is billings

I have written the query

```
 $currentMonth = date('m');
            $currentmonthbilling = DB::table("billings")
            ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount)"))
                        ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth]);
```

I want to get the total amount paid by everyone for the current month

Comment: Please post the uses of $currentmonthbilling object... because laravel returns the query object as for givevn condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get query result you must have to add `get()` at the end.

like:

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
$currentmonthbilling = DB::table("billings")
       ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
       ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])
       ->get();
```

Comment: It displays tags:      [{"SUM(amount)":16750}]

Comment: Try now edited the ans... you should get `[{"total":16750}] ` now

Comment: @user11352561 does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum(DB::raw('amount'))` in place of `select(DB::raw("SUM(amount)"))`

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
     $currentmonthbilling = DB::table("billings")
                              ->sum(DB::raw('amount'))
                              ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])->get();
```